# How to cluster similar objects into fixed size groups?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, randomized-algorithms, greedy-algorithms, cluster

I have $n$ people each of which can meet on certain days of the week. I want to group them into $\frac{n}{k}$ groups of size $k$ such that all people in a group can meet on a day.

eg - Suppose there are 3 people who are free on (M,T,W,Th,F), (M,W) and (W,Th,F) respectively. They can all be placed in the same group since all of them can meet on Wednesday.

Comment: @PålGD Edited and made it simpler.

Comment: Superpositions are allowed?

Comment: It's probably NP-hard.  Check out _set cover_.  Or maybe red-blue dominating set on bipartite graphs?  With days on one side and people on the other side of the bipartition?

Answer (score -1):

Just model your problem with graph and use any of the widely known search algorithm to help traverse your graph. After doing that, if you have any problem, let us know.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, this answer doesn't have enough detail to be useful. It's not at all obvious to me how to use a search algorithm to do what sounds much more like clustering than traversal. How do you propose to do that?